# Why is my 'date' command output showing '00' as the month in bash shell?

Tags: bash, date

I was trying to output the date equivalent to 1932-08-31 in a 'DD-MM-YYYY' format to which I am adding 7 months, but it seems like the number referencing the month is '00'.

Here is the command and its output:

```
$ date -d "1932-08-31+7 month" '+%d-%M-%Y'
31-00-1933
```

I've tried adding different numbers of months, days, and years, but no matter what I add the month output number seems to always be '00'.

I have tried the following commands:

```
$ date -d "19320831+8 days+1 month" '+%d-%M-%Y'
09-00-1932
$ date -d "19320831+8 days" '+%d-%M-%Y'
08-00-1932
```

Answer (score 2):

`%M` is minutes, not month. You want lowercase `%m`.